# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{n^k k^n}$ is convergent, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, see the definition from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html). We consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{n^k k^n}.\tag{1}$$
I would like to know how to prove that this series is convergent.

My attempt was to use absolute convergence, but it fails:
$$ \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{n^k k^n} \right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k k^n},$$ and 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k k^n}$ is divergent, since (this last series has positive terms) 
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k k^n}=\left(\sum_{n=1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k k^n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{ k}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k k^n}.$$

As motivation, but it is mainly curiosity, I've created $(1)$ when while reading  [1] and I tried to set variations of those identities, calculating approximations  with Wolfram Alpha, of series like than previous, or $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{\mu(j)}{kj(k+j)}$$ or $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^k\frac{\mu(k)\mu(j)}{kj(k+j)}.$$ I don't know if such series were in the literature, or are interestings.

> **Question.** Can you prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\mu(k)}{n^k k^n}$$ does converge? **Many thanks.**

One can see my approximation with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) if type the code

`sum mu(n)mu(k)/(k^n n^k), n=1 to 30, from k=1 to 30`

or

`sum mu(n)mu(k)/(k^n n^k), n=1 to 100, from k=1 to 100`.

### References:

[1] Whalter Janous, *Around Apéry's Constant*, Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics, volume 7, issue 1, article 35 (2006).

Comment: Hint: analyze $\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}$.

Comment: Many thanks @MarcoCantarini I am going to think in your hint. I know that were in the literature upper bounds for $ \left| \sum_{k\leq x}\frac{\mu(k)}{k} \right|$. Any case feel free to add hints or your approach as an answer.

Comment: I believe @MarcoCantarini is hinting at something like the Riemann zeta function...